# How to allow a "google logged in" user to login with email the next time?

Tags: php, google-signin

For example: the first time user logged in using "sign in with google". Using the Google Api I am registering the user a new account with their email and obviously password(hashed) is not provided by google.

The next time the user forgets he logged in with google the first time, now he/she tries to login with the email directly. But the database will not have a password for this email.

How to allow user to login with both "google" and "email" of the same email address?

Comment: just take the password while sign in with google. so that user will remember the password with email

Comment: thanks @EmtiazZahid, but "sign in with google" is supposed to be one button click for a quicker and easier signup/login process.

Comment: the reason I am asking this question is because, I tried some web apps that has "sign in with google" option available. First time i did "sign in with google" then I logged out and this time tried to login with the same google email i signed up with the first time through the normal "email" and "password" login method. Surprisingly it worked (ofcourse the password i typed is same as my gmail's password). So I am just thinking how are they able to verify the password?

Comment: They are not able to verify your password with Google. I am guessing they must have had a session or cookie stored locally with your access_token stored in it. Since that token hadn't expired, when you logged in they probably checked for the token and if it still existed, sent you in a different path using the google sign in. You could always try using an incorrect password and see if it still works just to prove the theory, but first make sure you are still able to login with the correct password in case your access token expired.

Comment: @eResourcesInc thanks! does that mean if a user signs in with google first time and the next time uses the same google email but tries to login through the "email" and "password" method. We should just tell them "email" or "password" is incorrect? or is it better to inform the user "hey you logged in with google" so login with google?

Comment: I think that’s subjective but definitely reminding the user how they originally signed in will always be helpful and should be a better way to handle it, IMHO

Comment: thx @eResourcesInc, that was helpful! thanks for the suggestion!